# I need to dismiss my PopupWindow, but the dismiss function isn't working

Tags: java, android, dismiss, android-popupwindow

The title describes it rather well; A PopupWindow opens, and is used as a menu for my game. However, when I try to use a button to close the menu, Eclipse says "The local variable pw may not have been initialized" :\

My Java code:

```
package com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.PopupWindow.OnDismissListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public float goldCount;
Button minionClick;
Button storeClick;
Button storeDismiss;
TextView textGoldCount;
String textTotal;
private SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Set full-screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("LeagueClicker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    goldCount = prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f);

    //Linking the variables
    minionClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minioncentreid);
    storeClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.storeimageid);
    storeDismiss = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menudismissid);
    textGoldCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewtop);

    //String which will display at the top of the app
    textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";

    //Setting TextView to the String
    textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
    textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mechanical.ttf");
    textGoldCount.setTypeface(tf);
    textGoldCount.setTextSize(35);

    //Setting onClickListener
    minionClick.setOnClickListener(this);
    storeClick.setOnClickListener(this);
    storeDismiss.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.minioncentreid:
    goldCount += 1.0;
    prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit();
    textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";
    textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
    textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    break;

    case R.id.storeimageid:
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
           this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
           inflater.inflate(R.layout.storemenu, null, false), 
           300, 
           450, 
           true);
        pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    case R.id.menudismissid:
        pw.dismiss();
        break;

    }


}


@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    goldCount = prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f);
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit();
    Log.d(prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f)+"derprolw", "ejwfjbrea");
}
```

}

Does anyone know how I can set the button to dismiss the PopupWindow?

EDIT: The LogCat errors which are now produced:

```
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491): Process: com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp, PID: 3491
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp/com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp.MainClass}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp.MainClass.onCreate(MainClass.java:66)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-22 15:20:04.478: E/AndroidRuntime(3491):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

EDIT 2:

So, with some help and editing, we've figured out the code:

```
//Initialize variables from popup window
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
           this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
               inflater.inflate(R.layout.storemenu, null, false)); 
    storeDismiss = (Button) pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.menudismissid);
```

In place of "storeDismiss = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menudismissid);". The only issue now is that the button doesn't actually dismiss the menu :(

Comment: Are you missing a `break;` at the end of the `case R.id.storeimageid` and before the `case R.id.menudismissid`? What line is Eclipse complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use variable defined inside one case block in another case block. Because there is no particular sequence of execution for case blocks. Better approach would be, declare `PopupWindow` as member variable of the class.

```
public class MainClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public float goldCount;
Button minionClick;
Button storeClick;
Button storeDismiss;
TextView textGoldCount;
String textTotal;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
PopupWindow pw;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Set full-screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("LeagueClicker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    goldCount = prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f);

    //Linking the variables
    minionClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minioncentreid);
    storeClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.storeimageid);
    storeDismiss = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menudismissid);
    textGoldCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewtop);

    //String which will display at the top of the app
    textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";

    //Setting TextView to the String
    textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
    textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mechanical.ttf");
    textGoldCount.setTypeface(tf);
    textGoldCount.setTextSize(35);

    //Setting onClickListener
    minionClick.setOnClickListener(this);
    storeClick.setOnClickListener(this);
    storeDismiss.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.minioncentreid:
    goldCount += 1.0;
    prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit();
    textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";
    textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
    textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    break;

    case R.id.storeimageid:
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
           this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(pw == null) {
        pw = new PopupWindow(
           inflater.inflate(R.layout.storemenu, null, false), 
           300, 
           450, 
           true);
        }
        pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
         break;

    case R.id.menudismissid:
        if (pw != null) {
        pw.dismiss();
        }
        break;

    }
```

Also do not forget to put `break` statement at the end of first case block :)

**Edit 1:**
You can access view elements of the `PopUpWindow` by

```
//Linking the variables
minionClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minioncentreid);
storeClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.storeimageid);
textGoldCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewtop);

//Initialize variables from popup window
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
       this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
           inflater.inflate(R.layout.storemenu, null, false), 
storeDismiss = pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.menudismissid);
```

**Edit 2:**

Official doc for `dismiss` function says that

> public void dismiss ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Dispose of the popup window. This method can be
>   invoked only after showAsDropDown(android.view.View) has been
>   executed. Failing that, calling this method will have no effect.

So your code for case 2 should be

```
case R.id.storeimageid:
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
           this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(pw == null) {
        pw = new PopupWindow(
           inflater.inflate(R.layout.storemenu, null, false), 
           300, 
           450, 
           true);
        }
        pw.showAsDropDown(v, 0, 0, Gravity.CENTER);
         break;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working :\ This removes the error, but then my app crashes upon loading.

Comment: Can you post the LogCat trace of the exception?

Comment: Which is line 66? double click on this statement in logcat `at com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp.MainClass.onCreate(MainClass.java:66)`. It will show the line in code which is causing `NullPointerExceptio`n

Comment: The line is "storeDismiss.setOnClickListener(this);".
I've been messing around with the code, but I can't figure out anything - There's still no error, but the app just crashes upon loading.

Comment: Seems like `storeDismiss` is null. Are you sure button with id `menudismissid` is there in `mainlayout` ? Can you post the code for `mainlayout.xml` file?

Comment: Yeah, that's right; the button with id menudismissid is in the XML of the popupwindow, "storemenu.xml".
So, why does the code not recognise the id in the storemenu XML? What can I do to link the java code to this button? I'm quite new at this, so I do appreciate the help.

Comment: So now inflater and popupWindow cannot be resolved.

Sorry if I'm being a pain, my code just doesn't want to work.

Comment: That's fine..no problem..:) check Edit 1

Comment: Ahh, I see :) That's fixed the inflater error. Unfortunately popupWindow in the line "popupWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.menudismissid);" still "cannot be resolved". None of the suggestions Eclipse makes to solve it are working for me.

Comment: Ah! sorry..it should be `pw.getContentView()`.. check edit 1 again

Comment: No problem :) I actually tried that earlier, but it produces two errors in the line "new PopupWindow(
              inflater.inflate(R.layout.storemenu, null, false), 
   storeDismiss = pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.menudismissid);", saying "The constructor PopupWindow(View, Button) is undefined" and that there's a syntax error at the end of the line.  
  
If I put a bracket after ";", the syntax error goes away, but it then says "findViewById cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Ah, never mind, on adding the bracket, Eclipse then tells me to remove it, leaving me with the massive errors. There's actually: -Type mismatch: cannot convert from View 
  to Button
  -Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
  VariableInitializer

Comment: Okay, so I *seem* to have fixed the code, now the button just doesn't actually dismiss the menu :P
See my edited main post, please :)